# When does Tate spectral sequence degenerate at $E_2$?

Tags: homotopy-theory, homological-algebra, higher-category-theory, spectral-sequences, higher-algebra

For a spectrum $M \in \text{Sp}^{B\mathbb{S}^1}$ with a circle group action, there is Tate spectral sequence
$$
E_2^{ij}=\pi_{-i}(H(\pi_{-j}M))^{t\mathbb{S}^1} \Longrightarrow \pi_{-i-j}(M^{t\mathbb{S}^1}).
$$

I heard that if the $\mathbb{S}^1$-action on $M$ is trivial then the spectral sequence degenerates. My question is how to prove this? And how to calculate the state construction of Eilenberg–Maclane spectrum $(H(\pi_{-j}M))^{t\mathbb{S}^1}$.

Comment: You have a typo: "the state construction"

Comment: The statement about the trivial action is wrong, the Tate construction of the trivial action degenerating is precisely equivalent to $M$ being complex orientable (more or less by definition)